# Probability of A given B or C

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I know some formulae related to conditional probabilities of events conditional on intersection of two events.

But I have been unable to find any formula for the case where the condition is union of two or more events.

That is, how can I find

$P(A | B\text{ or }C)$

And in general

$P(A | B\text{ or }C\text{ or }\dots\text{ or }X)$

And what can be the continuous analog?

$p(x | y \in [a,b])$

When I already know $p(x | y=t), \forall t \in [a,b]$

**Edit: An approach I tried**

$ P(A |B\text{ or }C) = \frac{P ((A\text{ and }B)\text{ or }(A\text{ and }C))}{P(B\text{ or }C)}$

$ =\frac {P(A,B)+P(A,C)-P(A,B,C)} {P(B\text{ or }C)} $

For the continuous case I asked, I assume that $y$ can take only one value at a time, so the $P(A,B,C)$ term can be ignored.

I have not tried a derivation, but just by analogy, I guess the continuous expression would be

$ p(x|y \in [a,b]) = \frac { \int_a^b p(x|y) p(y) dy} {P(y \in [a,b])} $

Is the approach for the discrete case correct?

I have just used analogy for the continuous case, is the formula I guessed correct? If yes, how to prove that? If not, what is the correct formula?

Comment: just define the event $D = B$ union $C$ and then calculate $P(A|D )$.

Comment: I have edited the question and added an approach I tried, please comment on the continuous part. And I am sorry, I tried several times but I was unable to fix the formatting error.

Comment: Isn't this just a logical follow on from some simpler rules? As in the probability of B union C is P(B) + P(C) - P(B intersection C), and for a sequence of events, that is the union of this result and the next possible event, applied as many times as necessary.

Comment: @Alexis Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1)
$P(A | B \text{ or } C)=P(A|B\cup C)=\frac{P(A\cap(B\cup C))}{P(B\cup C)}$

2)$P(A | B \text{ or } C \text{ or } \dots \color{red}{\text{or }X})$

what is $B \text{ or } X$?
If $X$ is a random variable, I think it is only valid if we  use it like $B\cup \{X\in E\}=\{\omega \in \Omega \mid \omega \in B \text{ or } x(\omega)\in E\}$.

so
$P(A | B \text{ or } C \text{ or } \cdots \text{ or } \{X \in E\})$ can be easily calculated by defining $D=B \cup C  \cup \cdots \cup \{X \in E\}$.

3) $P(X= x|Y\in [a,b])$  for the case  $Y$ is a continues random variable You can easily calculate it if you knowing $P(X\leq x|Y\in [a,b])$.

$$P(X\leq x|Y\in [a,b])=P(\{X \leq  x\}|\{Y\in [a,b]\})=\frac{P(\{X \leq x\} \cap \{Y\in [a,b]\})}{P(\{Y\in [a,b]\})}=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{x}\int_{y\in [a,b]}f_{(X,Y)}(t , y) dy dt}{P(\{Y\in [a,b]\})}=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{x} \int_{y\in [a,b]}p(t | y)p(y) dy dt}{P(\{Y\in [a,b]\})}$$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: And regarding the second point you raised, I am sorry if I used confusing (or wrong) notation, by X, I simply meant another event and not a random variable when I wrote $P(A|B or C or ..... or X)$, just like B and C, and not a random variable.